# How can I create a function that takes a URL as an argument and then is able to decide the correct way to import the given URL?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am tasked with making a tool that takes three inputs: i. the data file location (a URL), ii. the type of data validation strategy or data cleaning approach that needs to be applied to the data, and iii. the column number for which the data validation strategy or data cleaning approach should be applied. I am struggling with figuring out how to make my function be able to handle different types of datasets. This is how I started it as simply as possible, but I need to be able to take in different types that could have different delimiters.

[image: my basic outline of the tool so far]

Comment: First, please don't post pictures of code, especially you have it textually: it's literally just as easy (if not easier) to copy text and paste into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), yet an image breaks screen-readers, is bad for SEO, and (perhaps not perfectly relevant here) assumes we'll take the time to transcribe what you already have in text.

Comment: Second, don't use `data1[` within a dplyr-pipe on `data1`, unless you know specifically why you want to bring in a second copy of the data and possibly discard (or mismatch) it. It seems like you don't know what to do with dplyr, I suggest your first goal (and perhaps a single question) would be to discuss one strategy at a time, and either try in base R or go through some of the excellent [tutorials and vignettes](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) for the `dplyr` package. With that, please explain what the strategy is supposed to be (unless it really is just "descending sort of the column").

Comment: Last, the use of an argument-provided `colnum` for standard-evaluation of `dplyr` verb functions, you need to work around its non-standard evaluation semantics. That is discussed in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, and while some of it really benefits from significant experience using `dplyr`, I think what you need will be rather straight-forward. Perhaps just `data1 %>% filter(cur_data()[[colnum]] > 1) %>% arrange(desc(cur_data()[[colnum]]))`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I apologize for the wrong question structure. I really appreciate your help, do you understand what I am asking about the first argument? This function is expected to take datasets of different types/different delims and the function is expected to recognize which type and then import it correctly. I do not know how to start to do this at all.

Comment: I understand the premise of a function that has various strategies or recipes for data-cleaning, but to me it is something very difficult to encapsulate well in one function such that it is general enough across different types of data. There are some packages that do some of this already (such as [`janitor`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/index.html)), perhaps you can redirect your efforts to incorporating their already-tested methodology into your needs.